# How to find the indexes of the biggest number in a given List with duplicates using Java

Tags: java, duplicates, max

I have a list with values [1,2,2,8,7,8]. I would like to find the indexes of the biggest number. Here the biggest number is 8. 8 is repeated twice. So the answer should be [3,5] i.e. index of both the 8's.

I spent a lot of time. I am able to find the biggest number. I am not able to find a clean and easy solution to find the indexes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        parts.add(1);
        parts.add(2);
        parts.add(2);
        parts.add(8);
        parts.add(7);
        parts.add(8);

        Test ob = new Test();
        System.out.println("Indexs with max value:" + ob.getIndex(parts));
    }

    public List<Integer> getIndex(List<Integer> parts) {
        int big = parts.get(0);
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            if (big <= parts.get(i)) {
                big = parts.get(i);
                indexes.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Biggest Number:" + big);
        return indexes;
    }
}
```

The above code prints the biggest number and prints wrong indexes i.e. I am adding 'i' value to the index whenever it goes inside the if loop. I need to filter so that it adds only if the value is big. I am looking for a solution without two for loops. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, you just forgot to clean your list when you had found a bigger number:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
    if (big <= parts.get(i)) {
        if (big < parts.get(i)) {
            indexes.clear();
        }
        big = parts.get(i);
        indexes.add(i);
    }
}
```

A more elegant, but also a little bit slower solution would be to use Streams:

```
public List<Integer> getIndex(List<Integer> parts)
    if (!parts.isEmpty()) {
        int max = parts.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();
        return IntStream.range(0, parts.size())
                .filter(i -> parts.get(i) == max)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re almost there;  you just need to clear the list when you come across a new “biggest” number.  You can do this by adding to your `if` statement like so :

```
        if (big <= parts.get(i)) {

            // new biggest number, so previous indexes no longer apply
            if (big < parts.get(i)) {
                indexes.clear();
            }

            big = parts.get(i);
            indexes.add(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Recreate the `indexes` list when you encounter a new "biggest" number, adding that index to the new list (or clear the list and add the new index).  If the number is equal to the current "biggest" number, add the index to the list.

```
public List<Integer> getIndex(List<Integer> parts) {
    int big = parts.get(0);
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < parts.size(); i++) {
        if (big < parts.get(i)) {
            // new biggest, create new list starting with this index
            big = parts.get(i);
            indexes = new ArrayList<>();
            indexes.add(i);
        } else if (big == parts.get(i)) {
            // new instance, add index
            indexes.add(i);
        } // else do nothing, not bigger or instance of current biggest 
    }
    System.out.println("Biggest Number:" + big);
    return indexes;
}
```

**Result:**

> Biggest Number:8
> Indices with max value:[3, 5]

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to **clear** you indexes list every time you find value grather than big.
2. you need to **add** index to indexes if big and `parts.get(i) == big`.
3. you need to **check** if parts is empty or not.
4. you need to **add** index 0 to indexes before loop because parts can be with just one element.

this the code :

```
public List<Integer> getIndex(List<Integer> parts) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!parts.isEmpty()) {
        int big = parts.get(0);
        indexes.add(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            if (big < parts.get(i)) {
                big = parts.get(i);
                indexes.clear();
                indexes.add(i);
            } else if (big == parts.get(i)) {

                indexes.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

output ,in your example :

```
Indexs with max value:[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be resolved using a sorted map with a key - element of the input list, and value - the list of indexes.

```java
TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>> valueIndexes = new TreeMap<>();
```

The list of indexes could be created/populated in different ways:

- using
  [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 8, 7, 8);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    List<Integer> indexes = valueIndexes.computeIfAbsent(list.get(i), (x) -> new ArrayList<>());
    indexes.add(i);
}
System.out.println("valueIndexes: " + valueIndexes.lastEntry().getValue()); // lastEntry may be null for empty input list
```

- `Map::merge` is less convenient because many intermediate lists are created:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    valueIndexes.merge(
        list.get(i),                       // key: element of input
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)), // store index into extendable list
        (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; } // merge function
    );
}
System.out.println("merge valueIndexes: " + valueIndexes.lastEntry().getValue());
```

---

Similarly, the maximum element could be selected from an *unsorted* map created using `Collectors.groupingBy + Collectors.mapping` followed by selecting the max key and related list of indexes:

```java
List<Integer> maxIndexes = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
       .boxed()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> list.get(i), 
                Collectors.mapping(i -> i, Collectors.toList()) // build list of indexes
       ))
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
       .orElse(Map.entry(-1, Collections.emptyList())).getValue();
System.out.println(maxIndexes);
```

These approaches could be joined to get the last entry from the sorted map retrieved by collector:

```java
List<Integer> maxIndexes2 = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
       .boxed()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> list.get(i), TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.mapping(i -> i, Collectors.toList())
        ))
       .lastEntry().getValue();
System.out.println(maxIndexes2);
```